# Avoiding GCC compiler "incompatible pointer type" warnings

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, constants

I've written two functions. One for copying an array of `char` type:

```
void char_arr_copy(const char *src, char *dst, int arr_size)
{
    int i;
    for (i=arr_size-1; i >= 0; src++, dst++, i--)
        *dst = *src;
}
```

and another for copying an array of `char` addresses:

```
void word_arr_copy(const char **src, char **dst, int arr_size)
{
    int i;
    for (i=arr_size-1; i >= 0; src++, dst++, i--)
        *dst = *src;
}
```

I think that this is an important thing to show to a future program reader in a function header that the function is not going to change the content of some addresses it operates with.

And while the first function compiles fine compiling the second one causes the following warnings:

```
revert_str_input_arr2.c:30:14: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
   30 |         *dst = *src;
      |              ^
revert_str_input_arr2.c: In function ‘create_new_word’:
revert_str_input_arr2.c:44:23: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘word_arr_copy’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   44 |         word_arr_copy(*word_arr_ptr, tmp, word_arr_size-1);
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                       |
      |                       word {aka char **}
revert_str_input_arr2.c:26:33: note: expected ‘const char **’ but argument is of type ‘word’ {aka ‘char **’}
   26 | void word_arr_copy(const char **src, char **dst, int arr_size)
      |                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

As I understand one can't equate `const address` and `address` and this is the source of all of my warnings. That's a pity, cause I could do exactly the same in my first function with `const char` and `char`.

So the only way to fix this is to omit the `const` identifier, right?

So it turns out that I can show (to a potential future program reader) that I'm not going to change the `src` content only in one of my functions and in another I can't do it in any way?

Comment: Try `char* const* src` instead. That will be an "array" of pointers to constant strings (essentially).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const char **src` The "const correctness" here sits with the (pointer to) pointed-at item, a `const char`. If you instead intended the array of pointers to be const correct, then:

```
void word_arr_copy (char*const* src, char** dst, int arr_size)
```

Read these right-to-left: "pointer to read-only pointer to `char`".

However, consider this improvement instead:

```
void word_arr_copy (int arr_size, char* dst[arr_size], char*const src[arr_size])
```

Comment: Or if we don't want these to overlap, a slight micro-optimization:

`void word_arr_copy (int arr_size, char* dst [restrict arr_size], char*const src [restrict arr_size])`

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant either

```
void word_arr_copy(const char *const *src, const char **dst, int arr_size)
```

or

```
void word_arr_copy(char *const *src, char **dst, int arr_size)
```

(depending on whether the elements point to constant or mutable characters, respectively).

---

As an aside, I would recommand writing `dst` first, so it looks like standard functions such as `memcpy()` (which itself puts the destination first by analogy with `=` operator).  That will help reduce user confusion.  And prefer `size_t` for the size argument.